# How can I use a configuration setting to create a captcha validation rule?

Tags: php, cakephp

In my blog plugin, I want to create a captcha that users can change whenever the bots learn how to solve it. My idea was to have two configuration settings: 'Plugin.Blog.captcha_answer' and 'Plugin.Blog.captcha_question', and a default in case the user doesn't set it.

Then in the BlogPostComment model, there's a validation rule for it:

```
public $validate = array(   'captcha' => array(
        'rule' => array('custom', $captcha_a)
        , 'message' => 'Please answer the question, correctly and in lowercase.'
        , 'required' => false
        ,
    ), 
);
```

So I need to instantiate $captcha_a in the model. I did it like this:

```
public $captcha_q = (isset(Configure::read('Plugin.Blog.captcha_answer'))) ?  Configure::read('Plugin.Blog.captcha_question') : "orange";
```

It turns out that you can't call a function during class variable declaration.

How else can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method turned out to be making the validation a separate function, and passing it into the $validate array.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Answer (score 0):

Could you set those variables in the constructor instead?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a beforeValidate callback in the model for that:

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeValidate($options);
    $this->validate['captcha'] = array(/* your rules here */);
}
```